# Using Azure resource graph with .net SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to query my Azure Resource Manager resources using Azure Resource Graph with Azure .NET SDK. Currently I'm stuck at creating a `ResourceGraphClient`, I'm not really sure what value to provide to the `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[]` parameter.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It can help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, If you want to create `ResourceGraphClient`with `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[]` directly, it is impossible. Because it is a `projected` Constructor.  For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/dc23a39caf37d07f02512540d20c29866ff83759/sdk/resourcegraph/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceGraph/src/Generated/ResourceGraphClient.cs) 
[image]

Besides, according to my test, we can create a `ResourceGraphClient` with `ServiceClientCredentials` class.

For example
1. [Create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac)

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor --sdk-auth
```

2. code

```
public  async static Task Test() {


            CustomLoginCredentials creds = new CustomLoginCredentials();

            var resourceGraphClient = new ResourceGraphClient(creds);

            var queryReq = new QueryRequest {

                Subscriptions = new List<string> { "<your subscription id>" },
                Query = "where type == 'microsoft.web/sites'"

            };
            var result = await resourceGraphClient.ResourcesAsync(queryReq);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
        }

class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials {
        private static string tenantId = "<your sp tenant id>";
        private static string clientId = "your sp app id";
        private static string cert = "your sp password";
        private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
        public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
        {
            var authenticationContext =
                new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/"+tenantId);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: cert);

            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.azure.com/",
                clientCredential: credential).Result;

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
        }
        public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            if (AuthenticationToken == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");
            }



            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);



            await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        }
```

[image]